# GetHashCode for a class with a list object

Tags: c#, gethashcode

I have such a class:

```
public class Cycle
{
          public List<int> Edges
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            Cycle cycle = (Cycle)obj;

            var list1 = cycle.Edges;
            var list2 = Edges;
            var same = list1.Except(list2).Count() == 0 &&
                       list2.Except(list1).Count() == 0;
            return same;

        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
         //   return Edges.GetHashCode();
        }
}
```

As you can see, if two `Edge` Lists are the same, then I deem the `Cycles` as the same.

The issue now is how to implement the `GetHashCode()`?

I tried `Edges.GetHashCode()`, but the problem is that two `List<Cycle>`, with the same `Cycle` object but different orders, will be deemed different, even though they should be the same.

Comment: `Except` is a set operation which gives you only the distinct items. If distinct items are all that matters then may be using `HashSet<T>` is a better choice. It has `HashSet<T>.CreateSetComparer` which does all this for free. In any case if you want to compare the distinct items only for equality, then `!Any` is more performant than `Count == 0`. Like `!list1.Except(list2).Any() &&
                       !list2.Except(list1).Any();`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
override int GetHashCode()
{
  return Edges.Distinct().Aggregate(0, (x,y) =>x.GetHashCode() ^ y.GetHashCode());
}
```

It is simple, but should consistent.

Comment: +1 I don't see in which case it may fail for two equal lists, can you elaborate?

Comment: {1,2,3} vs {3,3,2,2,1,1}

Comment: is `OrderBy` really required here? I think this should do: `Edges.Distinct().Aggregate(0, (x, y) => x ^ y.GetHashCode())`. Or `(int)Edges.Distinct().Aggregate((x, y) => x.GetHashCode() ^ y.GetHashCode())` - the same, former being more concise.

Comment: @nawfal: I cant recall :(

Comment: OrderBy is not needed because of Commutativity and Associativity properties of the XOR (^) operator. Also the x.GetHashCode call in the aggregate is redundant. @nawfal comment has the correct solution.

Comment: @thepirat000: Removed it :)