# Comparing two custom Objects (using IEqualityComparer)

Tags: c#, asp.net, hashcode, gethashcode, iequalitycomparer

Firstly, I will say what I want to compare the following: My Custom Object (Item) has a List of strings `taxids`. I want to look if all the strings in one List occur in another list of strings (will be also another `taxids` of another Object (Item).

So, this is the class:

```
public class Item
{
    public long taxid { get; set; }
    public long contentid { get; set; }
    public string taxname { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> taxids { get; set; }
}
```

Then these are the dummy custom objects:

```
    List<string> numbers = new List<string> { "5", "1" };
    List<string> numbers2 = new List<string> { "1", "2", "5","3","564" };

    Item pr = new Item();
    pr.contentid = 2517;
    pr.taxid = 2246;
    pr.taxids = numbers.AsEnumerable();
    pr.taxname = "nameItem1";
    List<Item> te = new List<Item>();
    te.Add(pr);
    IQueryable<Item> er = te.AsQueryable();

    Item pr2 = new Item();
    pr2.contentid = 0;
    pr2.taxid = 0;
    pr2.taxids = numbers2.AsEnumerable();
    pr2.taxname = "nameItem2";
    List<Item> te2 = new List<Item>();
    te2.Add(pr2);
    IQueryable<Item> er2 = te2.AsQueryable();

    IQueryable<Item> both = er.Intersect(er2, new ItemComparer());
```

Here I use  a custom comparer `ItemComparer`. Here is the code for this:

```
public class ItemComparer : IEqualityComparer<Item>
{
    // items are equal if their names and item numbers are equal.
    public bool Equals(Item x, Item y)
    {
        //Check whether the compared objects reference the same data.
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;

        //Check whether any of the compared objects is null.
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(y, null))
            return false;

        //Check whether the items' properties are equal.
        return x.taxids.Intersect(y.taxids).SequenceEqual(x.taxids);
    }

    // If Equals() returns true for a pair of objects 
    // then GetHashCode() must return the same value for these objects.
    public int GetHashCode(Item item)
    {
        //Check whether the object is null
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(item, null)) return 0;

        //Get hash code for the Name field if it is not null.
        int hashItemName = item.taxids == null ? 0 : item.taxids.GetHashCode();

        //Calculate the hash code for the item.
        return item.taxids.GetHashCode();

        //return "a".GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

The problem is that variable `both` has nothing in the taxids field, normally I should have a list of "5" "1".

I know that the hashCode must be the same when comparing. but `taxids` will be never the same. Because we look for strings in another list of strings.

Anybody can further help me with this problem?

(Also a small question: If I return always the same hashcode for everything like `"a".GetHashCode()` => should this work or not?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is that you do not have **bidirectional equality**. depending on which side your object is, pr and pr 2 are not equal.

I am uncertain whether there is a guarantee which object is x and which is y in your comparer. What if `pr2` ends up to be `x` in your comparer?

with regard to the hash code, you are doing `taxids.GetHashCode()` - that is just a list and not a name and won't tell you anything about equality.

Answer (score 0):

```
return x.taxids.Intersect(y.taxids).SequenceEqual(x.taxids);
```

Your equality comparison does currently not take into account the different order of elements in the collections. As a crude workaround you could order them before comparing, or better add the items to a hashset:

```
return x.taxids.Intersect(y.taxids)
               .OrderBy(x => x)
               .SequenceEqual(x.taxids.OrderBy(x => x));
```

Also you have to provide an appropriate implementation of `GetHashCode()`, the default implementation is not dependent on the actual items in the list, so wouldn't result in the same hashcode for two different `Item` instances that have the same elements in the collection. A more appropriate implementation for your case can be found in [this other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630183/gethashcode-for-a-class-with-a-list-object).

Comment: When doing a instersect, it returns always in the same order. But thanks for the information

Comment: It will return elements in the order they have been collected (and even that you should not rely on) - in one of the collections. This is not necessarily the same as items in the other collection hence the re-ordering is needed.

Comment: Thanks for the information. And for the getHashcode method. Maybe you know more than me. Can I use always the same hashcode for everything? For example: `"a".GetHashCode()`. Because I will never have two lists that are exactly the same. In the URL you gave, the lists can be made the same by doing distinct, but I have totally different items in the list.